# Tap "under" SpriteWidget layer

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, sprite

I would like to combine Flutter SpriteWidget with common app design like this:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
        'assets/xyz.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        right: 0.0,
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () { print('Tap'); },
            child: Text(
              'I want to tap this!',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      assetsLoaded ? SpriteWidget(world) : Container(),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

But SpriteWidget is overlapping everything and the GestureDetector does'nt work... Is there any solution to tap "under" the SpriteWidget layer? Or any workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore touches from any widget using the `IgnorePointer` widget.

```
IgnorePointer(child: SpriteWidget(world),)
```